# Serialize a BigQuery XGBoost Model

Tags: google-bigquery, xgboost

Can an XGBoost model created in Big Query ML be serialized (i.e. pickle) like a standard XGBoost model created in Jupyter. The goal is to create the serialized artifact in Big Query and download it to local machine.  From there, it would be used to draw inferences in a different application.